# Efficient and faster way to find coprimes elements from an array

Tags: java, time-complexity

I'm working on a mini-project.
I'm tasked to find elements in the array that is coprime with all other values.
I came up with a method that uses a double for-loop. However, I believe the time complexity is not going to be favorable, especially if the array of elements is huge.

These are what I have:

```
ArrayList<Integer> getAllCoPrimes(int[] inputs) {
    ArrayList<Integer> coprimes = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] elementsCount = new int[inputs.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        int x = inputs[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
            int y = inputs[j];
            if (i != j) {
                if (gcd(x, y) == 1) {
                    elementsCount[i]++;
                    if (elementsCount[i] == inputs.length) //x is a coprime with all the elements in the array
                        coprimes.add(x);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return coprimes;
}

static int gcd(int a, int b) {
  // Everything divides 0
  if (a == 0 || b == 0)
    return 0;

  // base case
  if (a == b)
    return a;

  // a is greater
  if (a > b)
    return gcd(a - b, b);

  return gcd(a, b - a);
}
```

I would like to ask is there any way I can improve my method to run more efficiently? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: first you could start changing j=0 by j=i+1 to avoid checking things twice but that only divides the number of computations by 2

Comment: First, start with posting the code that compiles (does not have an obvious typos/syntax errors); then, please respect the Java Naming Conventions, and change `__gcd` with `gcd`.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is currently O(n^2*log(S)). n = number of items, S = size of the numbers

I believe it can be achieved in O(n*n) (which not necessarily is great gain).

- To do so, you'll first to new to compute of each element in the array their prime factors (which can be achieved in O(log(S)) with S being the size of the numbers.
- Store the results in a List for each number (so you will have N Lists). The average length of those lists will be the average number of prime factors which is given here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem#:~:text=The%20Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac%20theorem%20means,requires%20on%20average%20three%20primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem#:%7E:text=The%20Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac%20theorem%20means,requires%20on%20average%20three%20primes).
- Create a reverse map that for each prime factor give you the indices of the numbers that have this prime factor
- Then loop again through all the numbers and for each of them loop through their prime factors (which is more or less a constant based on the size of the numbers) and deduct the numbers that shares a common prime factors. You will then be left with the list of coprime numbers. For each number, this step is O(n).

Note: you're probably fine with the original code...

Answer (score 0):

i am a beginner in java so pardon my stupidity... but the easiest chang you could make would be change `a-b` to `a%b` in

```
static int gcd(int a, int b) {
  // Everything divides 0
  if (a == 0 || b == 0)
    return 0;

  // base case
  if (a == b)
    return a;

  // a is greater
  if (a > b)
    return gcd(a % b, b);

  return gcd(a, b % a);
}
```

this reduces repetitive calls on same smaller number.
that's the best i can come up with